# Divide a list of TimeSpan and list of Int to produce a new list containing int values of seconds?

Tags: c#, class, ms-access, timespan

I have an Access Database reading in a list of Athletes, their times and the distance of the events.

I want to calculate the pace of each athlete, and produce a new database with the `Athlete ID (Primary Key)`, `Athlete Name` and their `Pace`.

The pace will be the time divided by the distance.

```
private void StartSchedule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\A2 Computing\C# Programming Project\TriHard.accdb";
    string SelectQuery = "SELECT [Time Query].Time, [Time Query].EventDistance, [Time Query].AthleteID FROM [Time Query];";
    OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(SelectQuery, Connection);
    Command.Connection.Open();
    OleDbDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    List<PaceCalculator> list = new List<PaceCalculator>();
    while (Reader.Read())
    {
        PaceCalculator pace = new PaceCalculator();
        pace.Distance = (int)Reader["EventDistance"];
        pace.EventTime = 

        pace.Pace = pace.EventTime / pace.Distance;
    }
}
```

So I am not entirely sure if I am reading in the right thing, and the code is obviously incomplete, but you can see what I am trying to achieve from my last line there.

I have a separate class where my variables are coming from:

```
public class PaceCalculator
{
    public TimeSpan EventTime;
    public Int32 EventTimeInt {get; set; }
    public int Distance {get; set;}
    public int Pace {get; set;}
}
```

But again I am not sure I am using the right variable types for the job. The times are in `HH:MM:SS`.

Am I doing this the best way? and if not, what is the best way?

Comment: Have you ruled out using a field expression in an Access query to calculate pace?

Comment: First you need to nail down the terminology. You want to "produce a new database"? I doubt it. Perhaps you want to produce a new *table*, but in fact I suspect that you want to produce a *query* (often called a *view* in other databases) to display the athlete's ID, Name, and Pace. If so, please [edit] your question to clarify what you are trying to achieve (besides getting your #%^#$! homework assignment done :). As @HansUp says, it could be as simple as `SELECT ... [Time]/[EventDistance] AS Pace FROM ...`.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't realized you could divide in a query. I wanted the Pace to Correspond with the Athlete's name and ID, and I would like it in a separate database so the Event Organizer can just see the database of the Athletes and their Pace.